# Need some help understanding Artin 1.5.10 proof on the product of permutations.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, permutation-matrices

He writes:[image]

Why are both terms equal to zero unless *i* = *qj*? I really don't understand what's happening here.

Edit: The e<sub>*i,j*</sub> terms, as usual, represent matrix units. The *'pi'* and *'qj'* refer to permutations of i and j.

Comment: You should give the definition of $e_{x,y}$

Comment: It's a matrix unit. Essentially, e, is a matrix where the only non-zero entry is a 1 at the xth row and yth column.

Comment: I'd suggest you edit that into the question.  Do you know the product of such matrices?

Comment: Alright, thanks. I have edited it into the question. The product of matrix units are computed in the same manner as any matrix. The proposition was meant to address the product of two permutation matrices.

Comment: Yes, the product of the $e_{x,y}$ is defined just as any product of matrices. But can you explicitly determine the product of $e_{x,y}$ and $e_{x',y'}$?

Comment: $e_{i,j}e_{k,l}=\delta_{jk}e_{i,l},$ where 
$\delta _{jk}$ is the Kronecker delta